# while retriving data from firebase, getters are returned null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I am trying to retrieve  data from firebase. I have successfully established Firebase database but during retrieve operation the getter methods are returns a null value, how to retrieve that information?Object is not null but the getters are returning null.

```
public class ViewDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {

    public FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    public DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public ListView listView;
    public static final String TAG="ViewDatabase";
    //Oncreate
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_database);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.list);
        firebaseDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
    //Retriving data
    private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User user = ds.getValue(User.class);

            if (user != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "user is not null" );

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "user is  null" );

            }
            if(user.getAddress()!=null){
              Log.i(TAG, "address is not null" );
            }
            else{
           Log.i(TAG, "address is  null" );

             }
            array = new ArrayList<String>();
            array.add(user.getAddress());
            array.add(user.getDate());
            array.add(user.getEmail());
            array.add(user.getFname());
            array.add(user.getGender());
            array.add(user.getZone());
            array.add(user.getLname());
            array.add(user.getPhone());


        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

```
//JSON EXPORT
{"User" : {
"-LIN7aCLwUo7fdjSm5ij" : {
  "address" : "jagraon",
  "date" : "2018/7/27",
  "email" : "gurjaps00@gmail.com",
  "fname" : "Gurjap",
  "id" : "-LIN7aCLwUo7fdjSm5ij",
  "lname" : "Singh",
  "phone" : "8727050501",
  "zone" : "CARDIO ZONE"
},
"-LIN7iFVzA8eVShCSmwu" : {
  "address" : "jagraon",
  "date" : "2018/7/25",
  "email" : "livtaran@gmail.com",
  "fname" : "Gurlivtaran",
  "id" : "-LIN7iFVzA8eVShCSmwu",
  "lname" : "Singh",
  "phone" : "8725000740",
  "zone" : "STRENTH ZONE"
},
"-LIjA7Kox5dtN8jg9ywY" : {
  "address" : "chuuu",
  "date" : "Select Expiry Date",
  "email" : "cbjj@tuj.dhhu",
  "fname" : "dhhxc",
  "lname" : "cvhh",
  "phone" : "9856533565",
  "zone" : "CARDIO ZONE"}
```

}
}

HERE'S the JSON export done from firebase.

Comment: Can you post your database structure? i think your database reference should be `databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("User");`

Comment: Please edit your question to include your JSON data (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Done sir , please review my code again

Comment: @RohitMaurya here the structure as JSON file

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  JSON has been exported

Comment: @GurjapSingh As you said your Object is not null but the getters are returning null. So what is inside object?  As i can see in code your database reference is not pointing to User node did you tried with mine above solution ? can you post your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading from the wrong level in your database.

You're reading from the root, and then looping over the children directly under that. That means that you get a snapshot for `/User` and you're trying to read a `User.class` from that. That won't work, since there are no properties `address`, `name`, etc *directly* under `/User`. Those properties live one level lower in your JSON, so your code will need to loop over the individual users too.

One simple fix:

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(ds.getKey());
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
            User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            ...
```

An alternative (and possibly better solution) might be to only read the `/User` node:

```
firebaseDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
databaseReference.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```